# SQL Nested Select statement. Is it possible to try like this?

Tags: sql

```
SELECT count(select * from students) as total_students
FROM student_details
```

Comment: why you need to calculate  like this? what do you want really

Comment: Yes, it is possible. Will return the studens total count over and over again, one time for each row in student_details. Which is probably not what you want...

Comment: What do you want to do? I guess the query you want contains both `JOIN` and `GROUP BY`. Take a look at [mcve].

Answer (score 1):

**try this:**

```
SELECT count(* ) as total_students FROM students
```

Comment: Is this the answer OP is looking for?

Comment: actually the sql which is writed by @Ajith Sivadas is this. if he tells what he wants to do then I edit my answer

Comment: Your query will not return the same result as OP's. What OP wants is still a mystery to me.